# how to create external search quick filter and clear button for all rows data can search using single search Ag grid react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm new working with Ag grid react how to create external search quick filter outside of ag grid react,  user can search all rows ag grid data with the help of single search input and after search  user can  clear search input values. how to create i have no idea.

I have no idea i am following
[ag grid site](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/filter-quick/) 
but there is no exact search which we want.

Comment: why you cant use this [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/filter-quick/#example-quick-filter), any issue?